# Laravel5.8: Collapse is not working when I want to show the HTML code from the database

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

I want to show my HTML code from the database but when I decode it the Collapse is not working. if I don't decode the HTML it's works fine. Why it's happening?

```
 <!-- START TAB 1 -->
                                @foreach($faqCategories as $count =>$faqCategory)
                                    <div @if ($count == 0)class="tab-pane active"@else class="tab-pane" @endif  id="tab_{{$faqCategory->id}}">



                                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion{{$faqCategory->id}}">
                                            @php
                                                $sl = 1;
                                            @endphp
                                            @foreach($faqsubcat as $fade => $faqsub)
                                                @if( $faqCategory->id == $faqsub->faq_category_id)
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                                <a href="#accordion{{$faqCategory->id}}_{{$faqsub->id}}" data-parent="#accordion{{$faqCategory->id}}" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
                                                                   <b> {{ $sl++ }}. {{$faqsub->title}}</b>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div @if ($fade == 0)class="panel-collapse collapse in"@else class="panel-collapse collapse" @endif id="accordion{{$faqCategory->id}}_{{$faqsub->id}}">
                                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                              {!! $faqsub->description !!}
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: could you please show us your controller code?

Comment: class FaqController extends Controller
{
    //Show FAQ page

    public function index(){
        $faqCategories = FaqCategory::where('status', 1)->get();
        $faqsubcat = FaqSubCategory::where('status', 1)->get();
        return view('frontend.faq.faq', compact('faqCategories', 'faqsubcat'));
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `href` use `data-target`

example(Untested)-

```
<a data-target="#accordion{{$faqCategory->id}}_{{$faqsub->id}}" data-parent="#accordion{{$faqCategory->id}}" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
     <b> {{ $sl++ }}. {{$faqsub->title}}</b>
</a>
```